# Looking for yeast with dry flavour to pair with Nelson Sauvin

Tags: yeast, ale, belgian

I'm looking to pair Nelson Sauvin hops with some yeast. The hop variety is reminiscent of white wine, grapes and gooseberry. I'd love to go with a dry flavour profile, like a Belgium strong ale yeast, or something that tastes similar to French or Belgian cider. My previous attempts at picking such a yeast have failed completely.

Also it needs to ferment at 66-70°F (19-21°C). 60% attenuation or higher is fine. Ability flocculate doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What style of beer are you planning to brew with it? I suggest picking a yeast acording to this style, not so much the hop variety.

Belgian beer styles are usually quite dry, patially due to the yeast but also due to the ingredients used (sugars) and the low mash temps / multiple mash steps. Belgian yeasts do add a lot of flavors which might not pair well with the nelson. One Belgian yeast that comes to mind is the T58 from Safale. It is relative flavour natural but leaves a bit of peppery spiciness, could pair well with the white wine character.

Another option is a wine yeast. There are some excellent beer recipes out there that use a wine yeast. e.g: http://www.candisyrup.com/uploads/6/0/3/5/6035776/tripel_karmeliet_-_004a.pdf uses WLP720 Sweet Mead/Wine

Those temperature ranges are fine for almost every ale yeast. Most yeast will ferment well above 60%. (some Belgian yeasts in the right conditions - sugars/mash/temps - are able to attenuate over 90% )

Comment: So far I've been considering a Belgian Strong Ale or a Witbier. But more importantly I'd like to get a feel for hop, so I plan to make it a single hop ale of sorts.

Comment: In the end I went with a IPA instead. https://brewdogrecipes.com/recipes/nelson-sauvin

Comment: That is a great choice I think if you want to let the hop be more dominant. Another option if you specifically want to combine it with a certain yeast is to brew the batch as normal and split ferment and dry hop with different amounts. I've done this once with a homegrown 'mystery' hop and gives it a good approximation about what is an appropriate amount and what is too much.

Comment: It turned out quite good. I'm happy with it.